# 404 on internal pages, in all sites in my local server

Tags: permalinks, 404-error

I have a local Apache server, **with module rewrite loaded**, all my Wordpress files in this server fail to find internal pages whenever permalinks options are set to something different than *simple*.

Setting permalinks options to anything different or saving changes to force *.htaccess* to refresh, as many answers suggest, is not working in this case.

*.htaccess* has **777** file permissions.

This is the list of loaded modules in Apache:

> core mod_so mod_watchdog http_core mod_log_config mod_logio mod_version mod_unixd mod_access_compat mod_alias mod_auth_basic mod_authn_core mod_authn_file mod_authz_core mod_authz_host mod_authz_user mod_autoindex mod_deflate mod_dir mod_env mod_filter mod_mime prefork mod_negotiation mod_php7 mod_reqtimeout mod_rewrite mod_setenvif mod_status mod_xsendfile

Comment: mod_rewrite module is active

Comment: Is this a new problem or has this always been the case since you set up the apache? Could be that your _.htaccess_ is not loaded because `AllowOverride` is missing, [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19692840)

Comment: I'll check that, it's a more or less new docker container, so this is possible, I'll check

Comment: @kero yes, that was it, if you want to write an answer I will accept it as valid. Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be related to your overall Apache configuration and have nothing to do with WordPress itself. By default, Apache will not load any custom *.htaccess* files, you need to set `AllowOverride` for the given directory like so

```
<Directory /path/to/site>
     AllowOverride FileInfo

     # etc
</Directory>
```

`FileInfo` should suffice, if not, try `All` and check the [official documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride).